# How to find phrase with dots?

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

There is some text like this:

```
*text text text Bank of America, N.A., text text text*
```

I need to find the phrase "Bank of America, N.A." and I use a regular expression with word boundaries:

```
"\\b" + Pattern.quote(phrase) + "\\b"
```

But it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
String line = "text text text Bank of America, N.A., text text text";
for (String phrase: new String[] {"Bank of America", "Bank of America, N.", "Bank of America, N.A", "Bank of America, N.A.", "Bank of America, N.A.,", "Bank of America, N.A., "}){
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(phrase) + "\\b");
   System.out.println(phrase + " = " + p.matcher(line).find());
}
```

The result is:

```
Bank of America = true
Bank of America, N. = true
Bank of America, N.A = true
Bank of America, N.A. = false
Bank of America, N.A., = false
Bank of America, N.A.,  = true
```

I don't understand why the result of the phrase "Bank of America, N." is true, and false for the phrase "Bank of America, N.A."?

Comment: Try `"^" + Pattern.quote(phrase).replace(".", "\\.") + "$"`

Comment: one note, your regex should be `Bank of America, N\.` instead, coz `.` match anything instead of dot.  The reason why it fail for `\bBank of America, N.A.\b` is because the position between a `.` and `,` is not considered as word boundary

Comment: Use `Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)(" + Pattern.quote(phrase) + ")(?!\\w)");`

Comment: Remove the second `\\b` and [the regex will match all the strings](http://ideone.com/n1PeB1).

Comment: @AdrianShum I use Pattern.quote to escape my sequence in \Q \E. As I understood your comment, you propose to escape dot between \Q and \E?

Comment: @AlexanderDyuzhev My fault :) I didn't notice the `Pattern.quote`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. Your solution is working.